# Need free sites that shows my app in different devices for android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to find a free website that shows how my app would look like in different devices and which allows me to create images of how the app looks in those devices. I have looked into the android emulator but apparently I need the minimum requirement of 16gb ram and my laptop only has 8gb of ram. Does anyone know of any free website that meets my needs?

Answer (score 1):

[firebase test lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab) seems to be a good fit here